# how to use one array two times in an array php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$b = array('1','2');
$count = 0;
$d = 0 ;
$input = array('ina', 'inb','inc');
foreach ($a as $key => $v) {
$count++;
echo $v;
echo $input[$key];
if ($count%3 == 0){
echo $b[$d++];
reset($input);  
}
}
```

I want like this output

```
1
a-ina
b-inb
c-inc
2
d-ina
e-inb
f-inc
```

Actually I want `$input` two times in a foreach loop. `$a` have 6 items `$input` have 3 items and `$b` have 2 items. I need

Answer (score 2):

You're keeping a few variables that you don't really need as they can be derived from the `$key` value from `$a`. To get the output you want, you could do this:

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$b = array('1','2');
$input = array('ina', 'inb','inc');
$len = count($input);
foreach ($a as $key => $v) {
    $idx = $key % $len;
    if ($idx == 0){
        echo $b[floor($key/3)] . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $v . "-";
    echo $input[$idx] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
1
a-ina
b-inb
c-inc
2
d-ina
e-inb
f-inc
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GJvcI)

Answer (score 2):

To make it more applicable, [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e2342453f3a2c5077919cd8ff3a743f2f5cd6c0)

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$input = array('ina', 'inb','inc');
$loop = 1;
$input_length = count($input);   // TODO process the length with 0 case.
foreach($a as $index => $value){
    if(!($i = $index % $input_length)){
        echo $loop . PHP_EOL;
        $loop++;
    }
    echo $value . "_" . $input[$i] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Based on OP's code you should really be outputting the value from `$b` rather than your `$loop` counter.